# Spending fraction of salary

Tags: fractions

I have this question and kind of confused...

> Mary spent $1/4 $ of her salary in for rent and $1/4$ more than rent for car payment. Which of the following could be the fraction of her savings if her saving is not less than $30$ % of the remaining salary.

A)$1/4$

B)$3/10$

C)$1/5$

D)$9/10$

E)$3/4$

one or more answers are correct.

Comment: Question is ambiguous.

Comment: @Genomeme  I forgot to mention 1 or more answers are correct,, sorry!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

s=salary
r=rent payment
c=car payment

$\frac{1}{4}s=\frac{4}{16}s=r$

> ... and 1/4  more than rent for car payment.

$\frac{1}{4}s\cdot \left( 1+\frac{1}{4} \right) =c\Rightarrow \frac{5}{16}s=c$

Maximum saving: $s-\frac{5}{16}s-\frac{4}{16}s=\frac{16}{16}s-\frac{5}{16}s-\frac{4}{16}s=\frac{7}{16}s=\frac{70}{160}s$

Minimum saving: $0.3\cdot \frac{7}{16}s=\frac{21}{160}s$